# Table question about the sidelines

Tags: tables

I want to delete the line above x3 and x4. Can anyone help me? So the line on the left side stops above x3 and below x4.

[image]

The Tex is:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|C|CC|CC|C|C|}
%\cline{2-5}
%&  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Nichtbasisvariable} 
%&   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Basisvariable} \\
\cline{2-7}
& x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & F & b_i \\
\hline

x_3 & 1 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 180 \\

x_4 & 3 & 1 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 90 \\
\hline
& -2 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\cline{2-7}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Übertragung des Beispiels \ref{bsp5} in das Simplextableau aus Definition \ref{def6} }
\label{tab2}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Add a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` as in `\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & x_1` and `\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & -2`.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use `\multicolumn` for a single column. Either you keep you present setup starting with `|` and declare a column without `|` in the first and fourth lines, or you remove the left bar from the tabular and add it manually in the second and third lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|C|CC|CC|C|C|}
\cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{C|}{} & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & F & b_i \\
\hline
x_3 & 1 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 180 \\
x_4 & 3 & 1 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 90 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{C|}{} & -2 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\[-\arrayrulewidth]
\cline{2-7}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{C|CC|CC|C|C|}
\cline{2-7}
& x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & F & b_i \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|C|}{x_3} & 1 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 180 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|C|}{x_4} & 3 & 1 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 90 \\
\hline
& -2 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\[-\arrayrulewidth]
\cline{2-7}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

My personal coding taste favours the second version but the result is identical in both cases.

[image]

Note that in the last line I added a small, negative vertical space corresponding to the thickness of the rules (`\arrayrulewidth`). For reasons which I never really investigated `\cline` results in a certain mismatch at the corners (`\hhline` makes a better job, IIRC). Without this adjustment the lower left corner would look as follows:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the `[-\arrayrulewidth]` adjustment. Can you provide a brief explanation, for the benefit of the un-initiated, of its purpose?

Comment: @Mico To be completely honest, I have never been able to work out exactly what the problem with `\cline` is `:-)` But you are right, I'll add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do with the environment `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`. With the key `corners`, the rules (specified by the keys `hlines` and `vlines`) are not drawn in the corners. The corners are computed automatically from the empty cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
$\begin{NiceArray}{ccccccc}[corners,vlines={1,2,4,6,7,8,9},hlines={1,2,4,5}]
& x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & F & b_i \\
x_3 & 1 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 180 \\
x_4 & 3 & 1 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 90 \\
& -2 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

It's also possible to specify the vertical rules with `|` in the preamble (as usual) and the horizontal rule with `\Hline` in the array (with `\Hline` instead of `\hline`, you will have better junctions between the rules).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{|c|cc|cc|c|c|}[corners]
\Hline
& x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & F & b_i \\
\Hline
x_3 & 1 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 180 \\
x_4 & 3 & 1 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 90 \\
\Hline
& -2 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\Hline
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.